# Difference between VAR and Keep statements

Tags: sas

what is the diffrence between var and keep statements in sas. both are used to select the variables in output. but which one to use for best.
I have tried both but could not find the diffrence.

Comment: In which context have you used them with the same meaning? `keep` is a `data step` option or statement and `var` is a `proc print` statement. Please add some code showing your usage.

Comment: `var` is not just used in `proc print`. It's used in many procedures to choose the variable to be analyzed our output, such as `proc means` or `proc univariate`. But otherwise @D.Josefsson is right.

Comment: True, I was a bit sloppy in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAR tells SAS which variables to print in a PROC.

KEEP tells SAS which variables to keep in a DATA step.